# how to get xpath for product name as hyperlink

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am trying to *get data scrape* from below link:

> https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=887961316995

But *not able to get the xpath for the product name* (you can check by clicking over the url). As it is hyperlink, so not getting what to code in **self.hasxapth**?

```
if self.hasXpath('//[@id="result_0"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a'):
           self.browser.find_element_by_link_text("Barbie Star Light Adventure Galaxy Dog Figure, Pink").click()
            if self.hasXpath("//*[@id='productDescription']"):
                description_list = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='productDescription']")

                description = []
                for curr_description in description_list:
                    if curr_description.text.encode('ascii','ignore').strip()!="":
                        description.append(curr_description.text.encode('ascii','ignore').strip())
                description_string = "|".join(description)

            product_dict['Product Description']=description_string
            print product_dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of following xpath you can get the product name. If multiple elements are found then create a list of elements and then get text for each element

**xpath**: "//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']//a[contains(@class,'s-access-detail-page')]"

Answer (score 0):

Page you mentioned is using **h5** tag  for the product name. You can use the following locator:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h5');
```